# How to allow nova resource action in Policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Nova 2.0
Laravel 5.8

I have one nova resource `Document` ( contains file url, related foreign key and title  ) for which I have defined `policy` with `create` and `update` false and all others set to true, the PDF is generated from another resource, so I don't need to allow it to be created or edited, now everything is working fine, but  with another `action` on this Document resource I am trying to download these files, giving me error "`Sorry you are not authorized to take this action`", so how to allow this `action` on `Policy`.

DocumentPolicy class

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Models\Document;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class DocumentPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any documents.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the document.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Document  $document
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Document $document)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create documents.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the document.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Document  $document
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Document $document)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the document.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Document  $document
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Document $document)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the document.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Document  $document
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Document $document)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the document.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Document  $document
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Document $document)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function download(User $user, Document $document)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the policy class?

Comment: @ChinLeung I have edited the question with Policy class, please have a look on that.

Comment: @ChinLeung any suggestion?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it but I'm not able to. I've made a Document resource with the same policy and I'm able to download the file without any issue.

Comment: @ChinLeung Sorry for late replay, I have edited my question with model and resource code, can you please look into it and compare yours, may be that will give some idea?

Comment: Can you show the `DownloadDocument` class?

Comment: @ChinLeung give me one minute, I will edit my question.

Comment: @ChinLeung edited my question, please check.

Comment: Okay let me try. I will get back to you.

Comment: @ChinLeung I will be waiting for your reply.

Comment: You can have a look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error is because your `update` method returns false in your policy.

By default, if the update is false, Nova will not allow the action. To test this, you can try to set it to `true` and test it again.

To fix this, you'd have to change the way you are registering the action to add a custom callback to handle if the user can run the action or not like this:

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        (new DownloadDocument)->canRun(function ($request, $document) {
            return $request->user()->can('download', $document);
        }),
    ];
}
```

With this, it will check for the `download` method in your document policy instead of the `update` method for the action.

For more information: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/actions/registering-actions.html#authorizing-actions-per-resource

Comment: I know it, but I don’t want the documents to be edited as these are generated, so I am returning false there and want to allow action to download it.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes I know. The answer I wrote is to work with `update` set to `false`.

Comment: seems it is the one, let me try and get back to you, thank you so much for your effort 